# create log file just for ssh

Tags: ssh, log, sshd

I use ubuntu 10.04, contained ssh. I want to create a log file that stores all the activity on ssh (only ssh). Like in `/var/log/auth.log` but only for ssh. Like `/var/log/ssh.log`.

So, file `ssh.log` will saving all records of the client when using ssh to a remote server.

Comment: Which system logger are you running? rsyslog?

Comment: @Andy: yes, rsyslog

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I get your question right, but in `/var/log/auth.log` are (beside other things) log entries coming from `sshd`. I think you want to create a logfile with only those entries from `sshd` to see who and when is accessing your server via ssh, right?

`sshd` uses syslog to do the logging, in your case `rsyslog`. This logging is configured in `/etc/sshd/sshd_config`. The relevant settings are `SyslogFacility` and `LogLevel`. Look at the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man5/sshd_config.5.html) to understand what they do.

To get a single logfile `/var/log/sshd.log` which only contains messages coming from `sshd` you have to modify the rsyslog configuration. Create a file `/etc/rsyslog.d/sshd.conf` and put the following line in it:

```
if $programname == 'sshd' then /var/log/sshd.log
```

Afterwards restart `rsyslog` with

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: Thank you. Now how to have more detail in sshd.log file?

Answer (score 0):

To add more details to sshd.log, set the log level to verbose in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Search for the LogLevel line and change it to

```
LogLevel Verbose
```

Then restart sshd

```
sudo service ssh restart
```